# (FLASK, APScheduler)Error: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-connector

I am facing this problem multiple times.

Deploy SQL File into Remote database.

**scheduler.py**

```
from execute_sql import execute_file      # sql executor on remote db
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler # scheduler

scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)


files = **Multiple file paths**
for file_path in files:
    scheduler.add_job(func=execute_file, id=job_id, trigger='cron', coalesce=True, args=[file_path])
```

**execute_sql.py**

```
from mysql.connector import errors
import mysql.connector
from remote_db import db  # remote database connection


def execute_file(sql_file):
if sql_file:
    try:
        with open(sql_file, 'r') as sql_f:
            sql = sql_f.read()

        cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor.execute(sql, multi=True)
        db.commit()
    except errors.Error as e:
        console.error(f'[ ERROR ]: Error while Executing {str(e)}')
        console.error(f'[ ERROR ]: Rolling back ...')
        db.rollback()
        return False, str(e)
    except Exception as e:
        console.error(f'[ ERROR ]: Error while Executing {str(e)}')
        console.error(f'[ ERROR ]: Rolling back ...')
        db.rollback()
        return False, str(e)
    finally:     
        cursor.close() 
        db.close()
    console.info(f'[ INFO ]: "Transaction committed....')
    return True, "Transaction committed."
else:
    console.error(f'[ ERROR ]: Sql File not found ...')
    return False, "Sql File not found"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 9, in execute_file
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", 
line 425, in commit
self._cmysql.commit()
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

**sql_file.sql**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS video_games;
CREATE DATABASE video_games;
USE video_games;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS video_games.genre;

CREATE TABLE video_games.genre (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  genre_name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_genre PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO video_games.genre (id, genre_name) VALUES
(1,'Action'),
(2,'Adventure'),
```

Comment: I'd suspect that the results from a _previous_ cursor execution on the connection have not been read.

Comment: how can I check the previous cursor execution??

Comment: You need to check what statements have previously been executed on the connection.  It's difficult o help further because we don't have the history of the connection, nor the SQL that it is executing.  A [mre] would greatly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Try close the cursor before all the returns.

Comment: Please provide the SQL statements involved.  Also, since the error message usually comes from Stored Routines, the definition of any such that you are using.

Comment: it can be anything like DDL, DML, or TCL. I have updated my question pls check the sample SQL file.

Comment: APScheduler works in the same interpreter. So, you might be running into multi-threading issues. Your connection / cursors are getting shared across threads leading to conflicts. Either create fresh connections for every job or use a connection pooling.

Answer (score 1):

When calling cursors execute() method with option `multi=True` it will return one or more result sets which might contain data,  warnings or errors.

In your SQL example you should get an error for the INSERT statement, since there is a comma at the end.

So before you commit or rollback a transaction you have to iterate over result sets.

```
for result in cursor.execute(sql, multi=True):
    try:
        result.fetchall()
    except:
        .....
```

Please note that the rollback() method will have no effect, since you can't rollback DDL statements.